# ternary wont't work on individual div in ng-repeat with ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to change the color of a div using ng-click repeated five times with ng-repeat. It applies the class to all five iterations of div.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<div  ng-class="tileOn ? 'tile' : 'red-tile'"ng-click="itemClicked()"  ></div></div>
```

This is my function that's handling the change.

```
angular.module("GameApp",[]).controller('GameCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [{box:1},{box:1},{box:1},{box:1},{box:1}];

    $scope.itemClicked = function () {
         $scope.tileOn = !$scope.tileOn;
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `$scope.activeItem` and use that within `ng-class`

```
<div  ng-class="item==activeItem ? 'tile' : 'red-tile'" ng-click="itemClicked(item)"  ></div>

$scope.itemClicked = function(item){
   $scope.activeItem = item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed